# user location disappears, then reappears a minute later

Tags: ios, objective-c, mkmapview, core-location

When reloading data to show on a MKMapView, the pin will disappear for a minute but then reappear, I have set the `self.mapView.showsUserLocation=YES;` in several places in my code and I also have this method to try and stop it from vanishing:

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didUpdateUserLocation:(MKUserLocation *)userLocation {
    self.mapView.showsUserLocation=YES;
}
```

What can cause the user location to disappear?

Comment: hmm... Does this happen on the device or the simulator? or both?

Comment: Just the device as far as I can tell (other side of the world for me on the sim)